# Retrieve list if list is a value to a key pair for python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am using python 3.xxx

I have saved a whole list of strings in my dictionary..

```
dict = { 'somekey' = '['one','two','three'...]......... *to n*}
```

now if I know the `key = 'somekey'`, how can I retrieve the value, the whole list. I have tried

```
dict.get(key,0)
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? That isn't an adequate problem specification. Please check out [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your quotes are weirdly placed, this could explain your error. Use a full example that reproduces your error

Answer (score 0):

First thing, avoid using python keywords as variable names, this leads to [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) which causes hard to find bugs.

To get the value from a dictionary, just index the dictionary with the key.

```
>>> dct = {'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'bar': [6, 7, 8]}
>>> dct['foo']
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The same principle holds for default dicts. Remember to instantiate you default dict correctly.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict as ddict
>>> dct2 = ddct(list)
>>> dct2['foo'] = [1, 2, 3]
>>> dct2['bar'] = [3, 4, 5]
>>> dct2
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'foo': [1, 2, 3], 'bar': [3, 4, 5]})
>>> dct2['foo']
[1, 2, 3]
```

This handles lists, including lists of mixed types:

```
>>> dct['qux'] = "You're welcome Taha".split()
>>> dct['xer'] = ['a', 1, 'c']
>>> dct['qux']
["You're", 'welcome', 'Taha']
>>> dct['xer']
['a', 1, 'c']
```

Comment: NameError: name 'foo' is not defined.  You probably meant dct['foo']

Comment: I have fixed the typo

Comment: I am using defaultdict(), it always returns an empty list. I have debugged the program and the list is not empty

Comment: I have expanded the answer to default dicts. PS: you should have included the fact that you used default dicts in your question

Comment: This is my very first thread/question on this site. I will be specific next time.

Comment: No worries @TahaGilani. If you find the answer useful please accept  it (so the issue is closed) and upvote

Comment: Your example has list of numbers, my problem is handling with list of strings and by the syntax you have provided returns a null if I do dct2['foo'] if my dct2['foo'] = ['thank','you','for','the','support']

Comment: It should work, I have tested it and updated the example even further